# Can I put a button over ImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How can I put a Round Rect Button over a imageView,

My imageView: `self.view addSubview:myImage`

**UPDATE**

Thanks all of you!
These really help me.

Comment: [myImage addSubview:<button_name> ];

Comment: you can add it as UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(....); 
[imageView addSubview:myButton];

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(10,20,30,40); // set the size of the button here
[myImage addSubview:myButton];
[self.view addSubView:myImage];
```

Comment: You also need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for the image view (it's off by default for `UIImageView`), otherwise the button won't receive any touches.

Answer (score 2):

```
 UIImageView *contentView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)];
[contentView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"helloworld.png"]];

UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc] init];    
b.center=CGPointMake(160, 240);
[b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[contentView addSubview:b];

// Provide support for auto-rotation and resizing
contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

contentView.userIntractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubView:contentView];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just add the `UIButton` (with type `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom`) in `UIView` after adding the imageView.

```
  UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
  imgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
  imgview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
  UIButton *theButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  theButton.tag=i;
  [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  imgview.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 95, 115);
  [self.view addSubview:imgview];
  theButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 95, 115);
  [imgview addSubview:theButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the UIButton (with type RoundedRectType) in View after adding the imageView.

Comment: or add the UIButton to the imageView even

Comment: Yes you can add it by [self.imageView addSubView:yourButton];

Comment: but you have to specify x and y coordinates according to ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(....); // specify the frame of the button as per your requirement
[imageView addSubview:myButton];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`
```

You need to set the user interaction of the image view to `TRUE` as by default the interaction is `FALSE`.